# Grouping rows with Dataframe.Groupby, but keeping other fields as well apart from columns mentioned in Grouper

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

[image: Dataframe]

I wanted to group the rows according to the frequency of occurrence of the entries in column "Detection date & Time" within one hour per type of entry in "Detection_location".
So I used the following code:

```
df2 = df1.groupby([pd.Grouper(key = 'Detection Date & Time', freq = 'H'),df1.Detection_Location]).size().reset_index(name = 'Tags')
```

This code is giving me this output:

[image: Result Groupby]

But I do not want to lose other columns as well as they are crucial for further analysis. I would not like to average the columns as well so not using the `.agg` function.

I would like to have an output like the following:

[image: Sample answer]

What else should I add in the group by function to get this output?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: could you please paste some data in here so that we easily copy the data?

Comment: @pythonic833 - Sure :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make some example data:

```
import random
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_string': [''.join(random.choice('abcdefg') for i in range(5)) for x in range(9)]
              ,'col_int': [random.randint(1, 100) for n in range(9)]
              ,'col_time': [datetime(2019,8,1,x // 3,10) for x in range(9)]
             })

## Input data:
# col_string,col_int,col_time
# ggagg,93,2019-08-01 00:10:00
# faeab,53,2019-08-01 00:10:00
# fbgeg,45,2019-08-01 00:10:00
# bfebe,75,2019-08-01 01:10:00
# cacbb,66,2019-08-01 01:10:00
# aacfd,26,2019-08-01 01:10:00
# abggb,5,2019-08-01 02:10:00
# agcfe,20,2019-08-01 02:10:00
# agaec,10,2019-08-01 02:10:00

# Adjust datetime to hour.
df['col_time_adjust'] = df['col_time'].apply(lambda x: datetime(x.year, x.month, x.day, x.hour))

df = df.groupby('col_time_adjust').agg({
'col_int': lambda x: ','.join([str(n) for n in x]) # collect into a list
, 'col_string': lambda x: min(x) # pick a string from the group
, 'col_time': lambda x: len(x) # count
}).reset_index().rename(columns={'col_time': 'Tag'})

## Output data:
# col_time_adjust,col_int,col_string,Tag
# 2019-08-01 00:00:00,"93,53,45",faeab,3
# 2019-08-01 01:00:00,"75,66,26",aacfd,3
# 2019-08-01 02:00:00,"5,20,10",abggb,3
```